# Riemann sphere: Does it absolutely need two or more charts?

Tags: complex-analysis, riemannian-geometry

I am trying to understand the Riemann sphere. In [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere#As_a_complex_manifold) it is stated that

> ...[the Riemann sphere]  is the one-point compactification of a plane
>   into the sphere.

So it seems to me that it should be possible to describe to entire sphere using a stereographic projection (identify the northpole with $\infty$).

But the article also says that it can be described using the two charts with north- and southpole removed, respectively.

What's the ''smallest'' atlas for the Riemann sphere?

> Can one stereographic projection be used to fully describe the Riemann
>   sphere or does it need two?

As I understand it the definition of the Riemann sphere is the complex plane with one additional point ''$\infty$''.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Stereographic projection is not defined at the pole from which you project. A chart is supposed to be a diffeomorphism, in particular, a function! So stereographic projection is not a global chart. Furthermore, any manifold which isn't (homeomorphic, diffeomorphic, biholomorphic, as you prefer) to ($\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{C}^n$, as you prefer) requires more than one chart, since a chart gives a (homeomorphism, diffeomorphism, biholomorphism) between its domain of definition and ($\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{C}^n$).

Comment: Why can we not define the stereographic projection to equal the added point $\infty$ at the pole?

Comment: Charts take values, in this case, in the complex plane, not the Riemann sphere. The point is to give you coordinates which are ordinary numbers, unlike $\infty$, and the tradeoff is that these coordinates aren't simultaneously defined everywhere.

Answer (score 5):

As the Riemann sphere is compact, isn't homeomorphic to an open subset of the plane and is *impossible* an atlas with only a chart (homeomorpish!) .